# Refresh ListView on detect a change

Tags: android, listview

I did a Listview with inflated rows from another layout. There you can add rows by inserting a name in an edit text pressing a button or you can delete a row by pressing the delete button on each row. The code is huge so I'm gonna explain the problem. When I add a row, it isn't displayed on screen until I toggle the keyboard. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail (your code) so that people may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you forget to call `notifyDatasetChange()` on the adapter ?

Comment: what a stupid quiestion, thanks man